# Xamarin Xaml Resource Style Multicondition not firing with default value

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a XAML file in my Xamarin project that displays different views depending on the state of 2 picker views. The Picker View is a custom view that lets you display an Enumerator as a picker. The important part is, that the SelectedItem does fire the PropertyChanged notification.

So in my Xaml I define my style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SinglePressureRelativeHumidity" TargetType="ContentView">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger TargetType="ContentView">
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Mode}, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                          Value="{x:Static enums:HumidityCalculatorMode.SinglePressure}" />
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference KnownValue}, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                          Value="{x:Static enums:HumidityCalculatorKnownValue.RelativeHumidity}" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

This is placed inside the local resource dictionary. The References Mode and KnownValue refer to the custom picker views, which are correctly defined in the same xaml file.

I later have a StackLayout with multiple ContentPages each looking similar to the following:

```
<ContentView Style="{StaticResource SinglePressureRelativeHumidity}"
                                 IsVisible="False">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <controls:TemperatureEntry Title="Temperature" 
                                                       Temperature="{Binding HumidityCalculator.InputTemperature, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <controls:PressureEntry Title="Test Pressure"
                                                    Pressure="{Binding HumidityCalculator.InputPressure, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ContentView>
```

Where each ContentPage has its own Style with different Conditions.

Now to the problem, when I change the value of any of the picker the ContentPages get enabled or disabled as you would expect, the one where the style's  MultiTrigger's Conditions are met gets set to visible all other are set to invisible.

However, the problem is that when loading the view all are set to invisible. So it is as if the trigger only checks when there are changes made by the user. I have tested various things.

First I tried setting the value of both pickers to the wanted default value after the `InitializeComponent` method without success. I made sure that the Property `SelectedItem` does fire the PropertyChanged notification with the correct name.

Second I tried inverting the `isVisible` property of the ContentViews to true but then all were visible which also wasn't what i wanted.

So how can I trigger the MultiTrigger with my default values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by binding the `BindingCondition` directly to the Model which the Pickers set their values to.

I am not sure why this fixed the issue.